# Sidebar's background does not stretch to bottom with scroll

Tags: html, css

I am making a sidebar where I want there to be a background image and also a transparent overlay. The problem is that when the scroll bar becomes visible then the overlay background doesn't stretch all the way to the bottom anymore. I can't understand why this is happening because I have `height: 100%` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a reproduction fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/queeeeenz/7do4wysb/1/

**Here is a screenshot:**

[image: Sidebar screenshot]

**Here is my HTML and CSS**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .sidebar {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610643748471-2eae4a44bd18?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80') center center / cover;
                width: 240px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .sidebar::after {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                opacity: 0.55;
                max-height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            .sidebar__item {
                padding: 20px;
                background: white;
                border-radius: 7px;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            .sidebar__content {
                z-index: 2;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar__content">
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
                <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this https://jsfiddle.net/34L29huy/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif now the sidebar items are BEHIND the overlay but they need to be in front

Comment: play woth z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/34L29huy/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif This doesn't work when the scroll bar is hidden (full height) it doesn't stretch all the way to bottom.

Comment: height: 100%; to sidebar_content

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I do that then now it doesn't work when the scroll bar is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an extra layer above the background:

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: 
     linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55),rgba(255, 255, 255,0.55)),
     url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610643748471-2eae4a44bd18?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80') center center / cover;
    width: 240px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar__item {
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.sidebar__content {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__content">
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
        <div class="sidebar__item">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```